# Values from from select form field not updating in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form that with select items from another table. The items list just fine in form view. The problem I am encountering is that the other fields in the form updates just fine except the drop-down lists.

I have checked and confirmed that the fields are all include in the $fillable array in the model.

When i dd($myinputVariable), its showing values of all form inputs.

**This my form.**

```
{!! Form::model($member,  [
    'method' => 'PATCH','id'=>'member-regform',
    'route' => ['members.update', $member->member_registration_number]
]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('constituency_id','Constituency') !!}
{!! Form::select('constituency_id',$constituencies, 
array('require','class'=>'form-control'))!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('ward_id','Ward') !!}
{!! Form::select('ward_id',$wards, 
array('require','class'=>'form-control'))!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group pull-right">
    {!! Form::submit('Save Changes', 
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**My controller**

```
public function __construct() 
    {

    $this->constituencies = Constituency::where('county_id',8)->pluck('const_name','id');
    $this->wards = Ward::pluck('ward','id');


      }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $member = Member::where('member_registration_number',$id)->first();

          $input = $request->all();

         $member->fill($input)->save();


            Session::flash('message', 'Member successfully updated!'); 



    return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**My Model**

```
protected $fillable = array('constituency_id','ward_id');
```

After selecting a different ward_id or constituency_id, the value does not change from the older one after update. This issue has troubled my head for hours. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd element should be the selected value and the options the 4th:

```
{!! Form::select('ward_id', $wards, null, ['require', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

[LaravalCollective drop downs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#drop-down-lists)